# Why are my icons are not displayed correctly in albert launcher?

Tags: icons, themes, albert

Under some circumstances Albert launcher does not show the icons correctly. Either the system theme is not picked up or the icons are simply empty. What should I do to let Albert display the icons correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the icons are empty probably Qt is lacking an svg renderer. Make sure you have libqt5-svg (May be slightly different on some distributions) installed.

Further make sure that Qt has the correct icon theme set. Check stdout. Albert prints the icon theme on start. This is not a problem of Albert in particular, but of all Qt applications. This is a common problem and the internet provides solutions to the tons of possible reasons. Two mainstream options: Get Qt to inherit the GTK icon theme or use qt5ct to configure Qt.

Further resources:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications